# Find the file path of a specific file inside a zipped folder

Tags: shell, file, awk, find, zip

I'm struggling with my script. I want to find the full file path of a specific file, just like this example:
`/path/folder_06may2017.zip/file_B.txt`

I hope you can help me solving this problem. It will be really useful.

**Directory and file samples**

```
- Folder_01may2017.zip
      + file_A.txt
      + file_B.txt

- Folder_06may2017.zip
      + file_A.txt
      + file_B.txt
```

I have used this commands with no success at all:

**1st attempt:**

`find "/path/folder/" -name "*06may2017*" -print -exec unzip -l {} \; | grep -i 'file_B'`

**1st Output:**

`182118  2017-05-06 11:20   file_B.txt`

**2nd attempt:**

`find "/path/folder/" -name "*06may2017*" -print -exec unzip -l {} \; | grep -i 'file_B'| awk '{ print $4 }' ${PWD}`

**2nd output:**

`awk: warning: command line argument '/path/folder' is a directory: skipped`

**3rd attempt:**

`find "/path/folder" -name "*06may2017*" -exec grep -l "file_B" /dev/null '{}' \;`

**3rd output**

`/path/folder/Folder_06may2017.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$ find "/path/folder" -name "*06may2017*" -exec unzip -l {} \; | awk '$1 ~ /Archive/{zipname = $2}; $4 ~ /file_B/ {printf "%s/%s\n", zipname, $4}'
```

Comment: How can you use the output path as the input path for copy command? cuz copy command says it is not a directory, so there should be a way to read it as a string, right?